# php-ews Setting Flag (follow up) dates not working for Inbox message

Tags: php, exchangewebservices, php-ews

When creating a message with the `MessageDispositionType`:

```php
$request->MessageDisposition = MessageDispositionType::SEND_AND_SAVE_COPY;
```

And then setting the `FlagStatus` to `"Flagged"`

```php
$message = new MessageType();
$message->Subject = 'EWS Inline Image';

$StartDate = new DateTime('tomorrow 3:00pm');
$DueDate = new DateTime('tomorrow 4:30pm');

$message->Flag->FlagStatus = 'Flagged';
$message->Flag->StartDate = $StartDate->format('c');
$message->Flag->DueDate = $DueDate->format('c');
.....
```

I get two flagged items, one in the `Inbox`, and the other in `Sent Items`.

Only the `Sent Items` message has the correct assigned dates. 
The `Inbox` message flag does not accept the dates (displays as `NONE`)

[image]

If I use `MessageDispositionType::SEND_ONLY;`, the `Inbox` message dates are still not set.

[image]

Is there any way to only set the `FlagStatus` to the `Inbox` item instead of both; and why, if I am able to assign the flag start/due/complete dates to the message, would they only take affect on the Sent Items message and not the Inbox message?